# Is it good UX to have a table cell be both navigable and have a switch?

Tags: navigation, ios, toggle

I'm wondering if it's good UX in iOS to have a `UITableViewCell` (table cell) that is both navigable (meaning that tapping it will open another screen) and also embeds a `UISwitch` (switch).

Let's take the example of the *Personal Hotspot* setting under the *Settings* app. Imagine that this table cell (circled in red) is also navigable and has that switch on the right side of the cell.

[image: Personal Hotspot]

Would you consider this good UX? I've tried looking through all the *Settings* app and I couldn't find any example where a table cell is both navigable and has a switch. All cells either have a switch, either this > (right arrow) on the right side of the cell, to indicate that it's navigable.

In my opinion it's not good UX, because:

- It's not clear for the user that the table cell is navigable. (there's no visual indication of it)
- It's very easy to want to tap the switch and slightly miss it, therefore unexpectedly changing the screen, which can be annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No.

Is it good UI to put a button on top of another button? You run the risk of missing one and pressing the other.

In this case, make a [image] button next to the switch to go to the settings. Or something along those lines.